# make an image transparent in c++/cli

Tags: c++-cli

I would like to have an image that draws itself and also has the ability to draw itself transparently. I am using c++/cli.

The code I have to draw it is as follows:

```
void Gnome::draw() {
        canvas->DrawImage(gnomeImage, xPos, yPos, gnomeImage->Size.Width, 
        gnomeImage->Size.Height);
}
```

I just can't figure out how to make it transparent.
edit..........there doesn't seem to be any way to makeTransparent as there is for bitmap

Any help would really be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It was quite simple really.Just drew a rectangle over the top of the image.